# XPath to input element near a label?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am trying to reference a checkbox next to a label of a certain name containing an underscore.

An example DOM looks like

```
<div id="form-2143">
  <div id="wrap-1353">
    <label id="numberfield-1234-label">
      <span class="x-form-label">admin_user&nbsp</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1353" 
           class="form-field" componentid="cb1353">
 </div>
  ...
</div>
```

The aim is to select the `input` element so I can click it in Selenium.

The below XPath to my understanding should work

```
//label[span[contains(string(),"admin_user")]]../input
```

The problem is that the above works but only with 'admin' not 'admin_user'. 
Using just with 'admin' gets multiple results. I can only guess it is to do with the '_' though it could easily be a quirk with the site i am testing.
I also can't guarantee the order of the label and input, hence the go up then down

Comment: Are you sure that your expression works? Provided `XPath` seem to be invalid! It might be `//label[span]/../input`, but not `//label[span]../input`. Note `/../`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An underscore (`_`) requires no special provision in XPath (sub)string testing.

Given your HTML corrected to be well-formed,

```
<div id="form-2143">
  <div id="wrap-1353">
    <label id="numberfield-1234-label">
      <span class="x-form-label">admin_user&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1353" 
           class="form-field" componentid="cb1353"/>
 </div>
  ...
</div>
```

this XPath,

```
//div[label[contains(., 'admin_user')]]/input
```

selects the `input` element contained within the `div` that contains a `label` whose string value contains the substring `admin_user`.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to make level up again

```
//label//span[contains(text(),'admin_user')]/../../input
```

For example: with two examples of "admin_user" and "admin_test"

```
<div id="form-2143">
  <div id="wrap-1353">
    <label id="numberfield-1234-label">
      <span class="x-form-label">admin_user</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1353" class="form-field" componentid="cb1353">
 </div>
 <label id="numberfield-1234-label">
      <span class="x-form-label">admin_test</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1353" class="form-field" componentid="cb1353">
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]